# backspace not work in outside of regex in swift

Tags: ios, swift, regex, string, uitextfield

I use this method for patterning the phone number in UITextField at the .editingChange event
But the delete key only removes the numbers

```
extension String{
    func applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: String) -> String {
        let replacmentCharacter: Character = "#"
        let pureNumber = self.replacingOccurrences( of: "[^۰-۹0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
        var result = ""
        var pureNumberIndex = pureNumber.startIndex
        for patternCharacter in pattern {
            if patternCharacter == replacmentCharacter {
                guard pureNumberIndex < pureNumber.endIndex else { return result }
                result.append(pureNumber[pureNumberIndex])
                pureNumber.formIndex(after: &pureNumberIndex)
            } else {
                result.append(patternCharacter)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

use at the editingChange event

```
let pattern = "+# (###) ###-####"
let mobile = textField.text.substring(to: pattern.count-1)
textfield.text = mobile.applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: pattern)
// print(textfield.text) +1 (800) 666-8888
```

the problem is `space` & `-` , `(` , `)` chars can not to be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RegEx you are trying is to not consider digits only:

```
[^۰-۹0-9]
```

I'm not sure, but you may change it to:

```
[^۰-۹0-9\s-\(\)]
```

and it may work. You might just add a <kbd>\</kbd> before your special chars inside `[]` and you can any other chars into it that you do not need to be replaced.

Or you may simplify it to

```
[^\d\s-\(\)]
```

and it might work.

#### Method 2

You may use this [RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/FofkoJ/1/) which is an exact match to the phone number format you are having:

```
\+\d+\s\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}
```

You may remove the first <kbd>+</kbd>, if it is unnecessary

```
\d+\s\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}
```

[image]